# How can I parse the data having same tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the data for the details which are under same tags but I'm unable to do it.
the script which I tried :

```
import re
import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from flask import url_for
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin    

bigbash_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/squad/1134829.html"

r = requests.get(bigbash_article_link)
bigbash_article_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(bigbash_article_html, "html.parser")    

items = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"large-7 medium-7 small-7 columns"})
items1 = soup.find_all("h3")
items2 = soup.find_all("span")        

bigbash_article_dict = []

for div in items:    
     a =div.find('img')['src']   
     b = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/'
     c = urljoin(b,a)
     print(c)
     #c[bigbash_article_dict]
     #print(bigbash_article_dict)
for div in items1:
     a =div.find('a').string         
     print(a)
for div in items2:
     a =(div.find('span')).text  
     print(a)
```

I get output as follow

```
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099912.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/751925.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/599004.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/549144.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/986769.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099468.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1100136.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1100133.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/721225.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/818215.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/443920.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1080507.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/986785.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/517833.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099482.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/708777.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1093893.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/818165.html?alt=icon
http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099914.html?alt=icon

                        Virat Kohli


                        Moeen Ali


                        Murugan Ashwin


                        Yuzvendra Chahal


                        Aniket Choudhary


                        Nathan Coulter-Nile


                        Colin de Grandhomme


                        Quinton de Kock


                        Pavan Deshpande


                        AB de Villiers


                        Aniruddha Joshi


                        Sarfaraz Khan


                        Kulwant Khejroliya


                        Brendon McCullum


                        Mandeep Singh


                        Mohammed Siraj


                        Pawan Negi


                        Parthiv Patel


                        Navdeep Saini


                        Tim Southee


                        Manan Vohra


                        Washington Sundar


                        Chris Woakes


                        Umesh Yadav

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qwe.py", line 41, in <module>
    a =(div.find('span')).text   
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I get Attribute error If I try to parse the details inside the span tags. Is there any way to extract all the parsed details inside one list of dictionary 
The output I'm trying to get

```
[
    {'image':'http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099912.html?alt=icon','name':'Virat Kohli','role':'captian','Age':'29 years 84 days','Playing role': 'Top-order batsman', 'Batting': 'Right-hand bat', 'Bowling': 'Right-arm medium'}
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {'image':'http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/1099914.html?alt=icon','name':'Umesh Yadav','role':'captian','Age':' 30 years 95 days','Playing role': 'Bowler', 'Batting': 'Right-hand bat', 'Bowling': 'Right-arm fast-medium'}
]
```

Comment: What kinds of detail do you want? What is your expected output?

Comment: see the post last line, I have clearly mentioned what I'm trying to get  @kitman0804

Comment: Start with checking if `(div.find('span'))` is `None`  - if it is, do not access it's texts. Same for `div.find('a').string` .  Read and follow [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Then query the rest of the data you want, currently you are only querying the span.text in the `<a ..>` tag, the other information is outside of that. Use Chrome + F12 to get to the desired spans and think about how to get them from soup.

Comment: this [NavigatingTheTree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) might help you navigate to siblings and parents / up / down / across - there are similar ways to use find:  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. I am iterating over the li tags instead:

```
details = soup.find("div",{"class":"large-20 medium-20 small-20 columns"})
list = details.find_all('li')
bigbash_article_dict = {}


for div in list:
    image_div = div.find("div", {"class": "large-7 medium-7 small-7 columns"})
    image_present = False
    image_sub_path = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/dummyImage"

    if image_div is not None:
        image_sub_path = image_div.find('img')['src']
        image_present = True

    domain = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/'
    image_path = urljoin(domain,image_sub_path)
    bigbash_article_dict['image'] = image_path

    if image_present:
        details_div = div.find("div",{"class":"large-13 medium-13 small-13 columns"})
    else:   details_div = div.find("div",{"class":"large-13 medium-13 small-20 columns"})

    name = details_div.find('a').text.strip()
    bigbash_article_dict['name'] = name

    for span in details_div.find_all('span'):
        info = span.text
        if ':' not in info:
            key = "Role"
            value = info
        else:
            key = info.split(':')[0]
            value = info.split(':')[1]
        bigbash_article_dict[key] = value

    print(bigbash_article_dict)
```

Comment: How can I collect the text inside the span and b tag and store them in the dictionary?

Comment: Thank's @raffe81, this is what I wanted

Comment: what does this do key = info.split(':')[0]
            value = info.split(':')[1]       ?

Comment: It splits e.g. "Age: 36" into a list ['Age', ' 36']. Further [0] gets the first element in the list (Age) and [1] gets the second (36).